# compare validator for DATE type

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I want to compare 2 data in 2 textbox with DATE value,I used CompareValidator to compare them but it does not works for me how can I do? this is my CompareValidator code:

```
 <asp:CompareValidator id="CompareValidator1" 
             runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Date!" Type="Date" 
             ControlToValidate="SeconedDate_txt" 
             ControlToCompare="FirstDate_txt" Operator="GreaterThan"></asp:CompareValidator>
```

Answer (score 0):

What format are you entering your dates in and what regional settings does your server have? Date comparison validation is Locale specific.

Comment: I enter data with calender extender ajax toolkit

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Invalid DateTime"
    ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate">
```

```
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
            DateTime tempDateTime;
            String textDateTime = TextBox1.Text;
            if (DateTime.TryParse(textDateTime, out tempDateTime))
            {
                    args.IsValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                    args.IsValid = false;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you will need ajax control toolkit, make sure you have downloaded the correct version for each .net framework.

```
<cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender5" runat="server" culturename="en-CA" mask="99/99/9999" masktype="Date" messagevalidatortip="true" argetcontrolid="txtEditExpireDate"></cc1:MaskedEditExtender>
```

Comment: but can maskeditextender compare 2 value?I want to compare 2 value in 2 textbox